# Find $v>0$ so that $Av>0$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let
\begin{align}
 A=\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &  &\cdots & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{(n+1)\times (n+1)}
\end{align}
with $h=\frac{1}{n}$. I am looking for a $v\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$, $v_i>0$ so that $(Av)_i>0$. for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$. I know that there has to be such $v$ because $A$ is inverse positive, but i havent found a vector. Thanks for help.

Comment: $h$ is irrelevant, you can safely drop it.

Comment: This matrix has a lot of symmetries. Try solving it for $n=0,1,2,3$ and then form a conjecture about $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $v\in\Bbb R^{n+1}$ defined by $v_i=\sqrt i$ (for $i=1,\dots,n+1$) is a solution.